# Pipeline DeleteFiles@1 always fails due to folder being in use by another process

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run a CI build pipeline in Azure Devops. The last step of the pipeline is to delete all CI files to sort of clean up after everything is complete.

However, every time, this step fails due to the following error:

> ##[error]Error: Failed rmRF: Command failed: rd /s /q "c:\agent\_work\173\s"
>
> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

This is after it has deleted everything else and the `s` directory is all that remains. The funny thing is, the Resource Monitor doesn't show anything trying to access it, and I can delete it manually myself in File Explorer! I have set it to retry 10 times, but the same error occurs on every retry.

Also, when I did delete it myself, and it retried, I got a different error:

> ##[warning]RetryHelper encountered exception, will retry (attempt #: 7 An error occurred trying to start process 'c:\agent\externals\node16\bin\node.exe' with working directory 'c:\agent_work\173\s'. The directory name is invalid.) afer 49000 ms

Makes me wonder if this node.exe and the delete command are trying to access the dir at the same time. Or is it node.exe that runs the delete command? (Not too familiar with node.exe so I don't know what it's trying to do here).

It's a classic pipeline and the settings are as follows.

```
Source Folder: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
Contents: *
Remove SourceFolder: yes
Remove files starting with a dot: yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the delete files task.

[image]

The default working directory of the Pipeline is the Source Folder(s folder).

During the running of the Pipeline task, all instructions are executed in the source folder by default.

In this case, when deleting the S folder using delete files task, since the command is being executed in the S folder, it will show the error that the file is in use.

To solve this issue, you need to use the Powershell task to reset the working directory and run the command to delete the folder.

For example:

```
steps:
- powershell: 'Remove-Item -LiteralPath "$(Agent.BuildDirectory)" -Force -Recurse'
  workingDirectory: '$(Agent.HomeDirectory)'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

You can set any folders outside the current pipeline workspace as the new working directory.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have done it for me... Although I set the working Directory to `$(Agent.HomeDirectory)` because I don't know in advance what one will exist. (`172`, in your example is what I'm trying to delete!) - will accept in a day or two in case there's a more "official" answer for the DeleteFiles task

Comment: Yes. You just need to change the default working directory(S Folder). Then it will work.

Comment: Hey @KevinLu-MSFT, is the solution only applicable in Ubuntu and/or in Microsoft-Hosted machines? Because I'm running the command in a self-hosted Windows machine, and as I had expected, it failed due to the same error message as komodosp had. (I'm currently running into a similar failure as what komodo has) If I were to go into the machine, and delete the folder in question, I have no problem removing it manually, but not through the Azure Pipeline. FYI: I ran the command using '- task: PowerShell@2' instead of '- powershell:', if that helps...